# How to get size of all files in an S3 bucket with versioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know this command can provide the size of all files in a bucket:

```
aws s3 ls mybucket --recursive --summarize --human-readable
```

But this does not account for [versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html).

If I run this command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/myfile --human-readable
```

It will show something like "100 MiB" but it may have 10 versions of this file which will be more like "1 GiB" total.

The closest I have is getting the sizes of every version of a given file:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket --prefix "myfile" --query 'Versions[?StorageClass=`STANDARD`].Size' > /tmp/s3_myfile_version_sizes
```

Then take the sum of all version sizes.

But I would have to rerun this command for every file in a bucket.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

You can run `list-object-versions` on the **bucket** as a whole:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --query 'Versions[*].Size'
```

Use `jq` to sum it up:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --query 'Versions[*].Size' | jq add
```

Or, if you need a human readable output:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --query 'Versions[*].Size' | jq add | numfmt  --to=iec-i --suffix=B
```

You can also add a prefix in case you want to know the size of a given "folder" and maybe get also the number of version objects:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --prefix my-folder --query 'Versions[*].Size' | jq 'length|add'
```

Or you can use `jq` filtering to write more complex filters, for example, including only non-current objects:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --prefix my-folder | jq '[.Versions[]|select(.IsLatest == false)|.Size] | length,add'
```

If `jq` is not available, using the `--output text` option unfortunately results in tab-separated values, so here's a hack to force it to separate lines and then **add up the total**:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --query 'Versions[*].[Size,Size]' --output text  | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}'
```

If you have a large number of objects, it might be better to use data provided by the [Amazon S3 Storage Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html):

> **Amazon S3 inventory** provides a comma-separated values (CSV) flat-file output of your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

Comment: How do we do this on windows via powershell?

Answer (score 2):

Use CloudWatch, it will give result with all versioning.