# Huge varience in S3 Metrics - Cloudwatch vs AWS S3 CLI vs UI 'Get Size'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a single bucket which has very different Total Size and Number of Objects metrics between the S3 Management Console / CloudWatch, and the S3 command line tool.

**S3 Management Console Metrics screen**

- BucketSizeBytes: StandardStorage: 3.2TB
- NumberOfObjects: 172,000

**S3 Management Console - Get Size Dialog**

- Total Size: 264.0 GiB
- Total Objects: 127,030

**Cloudwatch:**

- BucketSizeBytes: 3.55TB
- NumberOfObjects: 172,000

**Command Line Tool**

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://mybucket.com
```

- Total Size: 264.0 GiB
- Total Objects: 127,030

The command line tool and S3 Management Console - Get Size Dialog is returning what I'd expect.

We are being billed based on the much higher CloudWatch stats.

I wouldn't be bothered if they are close, but Cloudwatch is reporting close to 15 x as much StorageSize than the CLI tool.

There is no replication on the S3 bucket.

There are lifecycle policies to:

- Clean up incomplete multipart uploads
- Send files +1 years to Glacier
- Permenantly delete previous versions after a year

Versioning is turned on but I am pretty sure it's not used; i.e. files have only ever been uploaded once. I have tested a few random files to confirm, and they all only have one, the latest, version, available. I am happy to turn this off at the bucket settings, but I understand this won't 'delete' old versions (if they exist) anyway?

I don't believe it's because of Glacier stored files either, as I only recently set this lifecycle policy up, and the size mismatch was present before that.

And I'm extra confused given the S3 Management Console UI > Overview > Select all folders > Actions > Get Size reports the same as the CLI tool, 264GB.

So, seleting all filers/folders in the UI returns 264GB, but the Metrics return 3.2TB.

Can anyone please shed some light on what's going on here, and how I can clean it up!
Thanks
Rob

Comment: Your expexted methods are giving you the total size of the latest objects and the others are containing older versions. You may have some confusion.

Comment: @Lamanus, I suspected the same, but as mentioned, versioning isn't used and all files only have one, the latest version, according to the S3 UI. Is there a way I can run a purge of any previous versions of files, as a triple check?

Comment: Try this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150572/how-to-get-size-of-all-files-in-an-s3-bucket-with-versioning

Comment: @Lamanus, thanks - turns out there was 3TB of old versioned files; but the whole directory had been deleted so wasn't showing in the UI. My bad. Thanks for helping me see the light. Have now permentantly deleted these deleted old versions :-)

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by 3TB of old versioned files; but the whole directory had been deleted so wasn't showing in the UI.

When I swapped the UI to show versions, the deleted folder appeared and then within that I could see all the old versions of the deleted files.

The following CLI statement helped me confirm it was caused by versioning:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucker.com --query 'Versions[*].[Size,Size]' --output text  | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}'
```

Comment: how do we run in on windows

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K a quick google of "AWS CLI on Windows" yields all the info you need; e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html